# in find, `-type d` get files an not only directories if used with `-prune`

Tags: bash, gnu-findutils

I use this:

```
$ find . -type d \( -path './2018*' -o -path "./S*" \) -prune\
         -o -print
```

to get all directories (`-type d`) excluding `2018`, `S1` and `S2`

The exclusion of directories work but I get plenty of files:

```
...
./git_wc
./budget
./budget/mail_0625
./budget/mail_0625/prez.pptx
./budget/budget_v2.xlsx
./budget/achats
./budget/achats/106-1396140_V1_20190731.pdf
./rh
./rh/file.docx
```

BTW I look for a pure `find` answer, I know how to do this with `tree`:

```
$ tree -d -L 2 -I 'S1|2018' -fi
...
./git_wc
./budget
./budget/mail_0625
./budget/achats
./rh
...
```

Comment: You mean "directories".  If they were called "folders", it wouldn't be `type -d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command's logic is "prune all directories that have names matching the glob ./2018* or ./S*; print everything else".  You want:

```
 find . \( -path './2018*' -o -path "./S*" \) -prune\
         -o -type d -print
```

Comment: Or in other words, your attempt was really doing basically `-type d -o print`. You could fix that by moving the parentheses, too.

Comment: @tripleee can you give the full invocation? I couldn't make it work without nested parens `find -type d ! \( \( -path './2018*' -o -path './S*' \) -prune \)`

Comment: With that variation, you don't need the `-prune`, do you?

Comment: You actually need. Without -prune it would recurse into dirs matching ./2018* and ./S*. It wouldn't print anything in them but it'd recurse. Try creating gazillions of directories in 2018 and compare with and without prune

Comment: Unfortunately, not in a place where I can test. Let me get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: `find . \( -path './2018*' -o -path './S*' \) -o -type d -print` seems to do what I expect.